# Dynamic Winforms control changing size

Tags: winforms, user-controls

I have this code

```
ShadedRoundedRectangle rect = new ShadedRoundedRectangle();
rect.Location = new Point( 0, nextY );
rect.Size = new Size( 200, 20 );
rect.NewText = String.Format( "{0} x {1} ({2} kcals)", ci.Amount, ci.Product.ItemName, ci.Amount * ci.Product.Calories );

panel1.Controls.Add( rect );
```

`ShadedRoundedRectangle` is a user control that draws a shaded rounded rectangle of size `200,20` as you can see.  When adding `rect` to the panel controls collection the size changes to `233, 23`.

The user control has `0,0,0,0` defined for both `padding` and `margin` properties and I am stuck as to why this is happening.

Comment: What are `Dock` and `Anchor` settings? How do you know that size changed?

Comment: For the user control; `Anchor` is `Top, Left` and `Dock` is `None`.

Comment: I put a break point on the `panel1.Controls.Add( rect )` line and then stepped over it with F10, opened up the `Controls` collection using the VS debugger to open the `base` object until I located the `Size` property and saw that it was different there.

Comment: Do you have some resizing when assigning `NewText` property? E.g. if assigned string is too long you resize control?

Comment: If `NewText` doesn't fit it trims off the end of the string with ellipses.  This doesn't cause the control to resize as the initial rectangle of `200, 20` is sufficient to hold the text.

Comment: Your code should not affect user control size. What I recommend to do - create new, completely empty user control, and try to add it instead of ShadedRoundedRectangle. If problem will not be reproduced then there is something wrong with your custom control

Comment: I will try that and report back later with my findings.

Comment: I have just created a new blank user control and it exhibits the same behavior.  Adding the user control to the panel's controls collection is still changing the size from `200,20` to `233, 23`.  I'm not sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question as I have found out what was causing the `Size` property to change, after adding the user control to the panel's controls collection.

Changing the user control's default font of `MS Sans Serif 8.25pt` to a different font, i.e. `Arial Regular 8.25pt` in this case resolved my issue and the size didn't change after the user control was added to the panel's controls collection.

There must be some bug that exists within Visual Studio 2012 that causes this behavior to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is the AutoScaleMode property. By default it is set to Font, which means that if the font size of the form is different from the font size of the control, the control will be resized.

Setting the AutoScaleMode to None, will solve this issue.
Also, making sure the form and the control have the same font will solve this issue.